# NodeJS: Nested SQL query for custom REST API endpoint

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, rest

I am creating a REST-API via NodeJS at the moment.
I created a MySQL database with these two tables:

1. table: physiotherapist = {(**physio_id**),(surname),(lastname),(*appuser_id*)}

   --> PK = (**physio_id**)

   --> FK = (*appuser_id*) and points on the PK of the second table
2. table: app_user = {(**user_id**),(username),(password)}

   --> PK = (**user_id**)

For the REST-API endpoint I need the data of both tables.
For example, when I want the information of user with the id=3 and the api-enpoint is like *'localhost:3306/appusers/3'* I want the data of both tables as a result.

This is what I got at the moment:

```
getUserById:function(id, callback) {
        return db.query("Select * from user_physiO_app where user_id=?", [id], callback);
```

it'S only the data from the first table, so how do I get the data of the second table?

Thanks in regard!

Comment: Look into the `INNER JOIN` feature in SQL.

Comment: @Evert it worked ! Thank you ! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved after the friendly advice of @Evert: I used the `INNER JOIN` syntax.

```
getUserById:function(id, callback) {
  return db.query("Select * from user_physiO_app inner join physiotherapeut on 
  user_physiO_app.user_id = physiotherapeut.physiO_user_id where user_id=?", [id], callback);
}
```